# How to show random images within a gridview in Android

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a number of images in my directory and I'm displaying them in a gridview in Android. I I have set a limit on how many images it displays but I also want those images to be randomly selected. At the moment, the gridview displays the first set of images (e.g. 4). I can come up with the random number generator but I don't know how/why the gridview is selecting the first set of images (e.g. the first 4 images).

Answer (score 0):

Your generator generates the same number so that only one pic has shown in gridview. Try to create a generator class and generate method. After hat create the class and use generate method  every step. It will give you different numbers on each creation.